# Differing result from os.popen() between Pycharm and stock IDLE [Mac]

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, operating-system

I've written a script to rename my photos according to the date they were recorded. It runs on mac and uses the CLI exiftool by [phil harvey](https://exiftool.org).

The command that create problem is the following:

```
os.popen("exiftool " + file path)
```

I wrote the script using Pycharm CE. I used the exiftool because it yielded the best results and was the easiest to use at the time. With the command mentioned above, I got all the metadata nicely formatted by the exiftool and it only needed to be separated and put in a list. I tried everything in the console of Pycharm CE before I wrote the script.

The script and the console of Pycharm both worked fine. However, I tried recently to run the script with the IDLE from python. The script failed because the return from the console was always an empty string. Upon further research I used the `subprocess.run()`method. The error was
`CompletedProcess(args='exiftool PATH', returncode=127, stdout=b'', stderr=b'/bin/sh: exiftool: command not found\n')`
The output was also empty.

My questions are now:

- Why does the Console and the interpreter of Pycharm CE find the exiftool but the console and the IDLE of python don't?
- Is there a way to include the installation location of the exiftool so it is found by the `os.popen()` / `subprocess.run()` methods in the IDLE and the console?

Many thanks for your help

AliSot2000

Comment: I used `which exiftool` and entered the full path instead of the command previously. The result was still the same: ```subprocess.run("usr/local/bin/exiftool /Users/alisot2000/Desktop/ASDF TEST.JPG", shell=True, capture_output=True)
CompletedProcess(args='usr/local/bin/exiftool [Filepath]', returncode=127, stdout=b'', stderr=b'/bin/sh: usr/local/bin/exiftool: No such file or directory\n')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At your command prompt, type `which exiftool` to find the full path to the executable. Then, instead of just calling `exiftool` in your Python script, use the full path.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, using `which exiftool` was indeed the solution.
I deinstalled python, reinstalled the newer version and tried the fix, proposed in the comment. (Using said command in Terminal and calling the command with the full path) It worked in the IDLE once I installed Python 3.7.  I ran previously Python 2.7 on my MacBook.

I still don't understand why 2.7 wouldn't work.

Anyway thanks for the tip.